# Start subscript in bash script in background so that it still runs when I close the terminal/ssh session

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script that should start an other script as another user and in a way that the script

1. Still runs, when i close the main script
2. Still runs, when I close the terminal or the ssh session
3. can be stopped by a simple call of another script.

What I have right now:

This is basically how `start.sh` looks like

```
# doing some other stuff
sudo su user_the_script_should_start_as -c "./start-in-background.sh $1 $2 $3"
```

start-in-background-sh

```
# doing some other stuff
# Start other Script in Background
```

How can I do those three points?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
nohup bash your_script.sh &
```

or

```
disown bash your_script.sh &
```

or

```
screen
```

But my suggestion is `screen` command. Also `tumx` is good to use.

And for your last requirement to stop script on call will be able to achieved by following command,

```
kill $!
```

Comment: or tmux, which is superior to screen imho.